# Date - Timezone settings in Php

Tags: php, function, date

I keep getting this error, I'm not sure what to do, it worked on other projects yet on this current project keeps giving this error below

```
Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelt the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /home/ediyeng/public_html/app/app.php on line 9
```

Below is the Code

```
<?php
  echo date(DATE_RFC2822);
?>
```

Comment: The message already tells you everything you need to know in plain English ...

Comment: And i see that thanks, burr what's an alternative code i could use? @CBroe

Comment: And what timezone do you have in the project then?

Comment: Does Nigeria have a timezone if yes, then Nigeria. @Andreas

Comment: Ok. What code do you have to set the timezone to Nigeria?

Comment: Here is the African timezones http://php.net/manual/ro/timezones.africa.php

Comment: Nothing? Ok... Then try this: on the line above $date=.... Add this line `date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Lagos");`

Comment: I'm not sure, haven't really worked with timezone, just device time and date for global projects

Comment: Thanks man it' worked. @Andreas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147952/discussion-between-precious-aniefiok-and-andreas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you either don't have a timezone set up or it's misspelled.

There are two ways to fix this, in each php file or in php.ini.

In each php file you can add the following line to set it to Nigeria timezone.
`<Edit> you could possibly also add this line to a header file you include in all php files if you have a header file </edit>`

```
date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Lagos");
```

Or you can edit the php.ini (maybe it's here the misspelled timezone lives too).
Find the line that looks like:

```
date.timezone = ....
```

And replace it with

```
date.timezone = "Africa/Lagos"
```